# Why cant we do PChar('*') in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

I wrote this code and am getting AV in it.

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  Var
     C : Pchar;
     s : string;
 begin
    c:= PChar('*');
    s := string(c); // AV here , but code works if i put C:= PChar('**') 
   ShowMessage(c);
end;
```

I could not figure out why .Does anybody know ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specific what you mean by "AV" exactly

Comment: Your code makes no sense. First, it works. Second, you don't need to typecast to `string`. `s := c;` works just fine without it, and `ShowMessage(s);` or `ShowMessage(c);` both work as well.

Comment: edited the code now . please take a look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AV means wrong work with memory. Get data from nowhere or write to nowhere.

Problem goes from different types of data.

> '*'

is Char, but

> '**'

is string

This will work fine with your code:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 Var
    C : Pchar;
    s : string;
 begin
    c:= PChar(string('*'));
    s := string(c); // AV here , but code works if i put C:= PChar('**') 
   ShowMessage(c);
end;
```

Answer (score 10):

With a one-character string literal, you're type casting a `Char`, not a `string`, so it's not a pointer. When you cast it back, it's still not really a pointer, despite its declared type, so it can't be converted to a string.

If you find yourself type casting a string literal, you're probably doing something unnecessary. Although you can give it a hint which type it should use, as the other answers here demonstrate, the compiler already detects which type a literal needs to have, and it's usually correct. Just assign the literal directly to the variable without any casting.

If you omit the type cast entirely, your code would work equally well for whatever length string you want:

```
// All PChar assignments, no casting
c := '';
c := '*';
c := '**';
```

Furthermore, the cast back to `string` is unnecessary as well. You can directly assign a `PChar`, and the compiler will perform the conversion automatically:

```
s := c;
```

Comment: I wonder if the schizophrenia of string literals is documented anywhere. I cannot find it. Seems like a crazy design for `'a'` to be of one type and `'aa'` to be of a different type. I'm liking the syntax of C's literals right now.

Comment: @David, the best I can find is where it says "[a character string with one character, single or multibyte, is compatible with any character type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Character_Strings)." That's not quite as detailed as we'd want, though. I often like Delphi's "magic" string literals. Problems generally only occur when we try to "help" the compiler in cases where it never needed help, as in this question. When it doesn't know the right type, it issues an error message. If it hasn't done that, then we shouldn't be type-casting.

Comment: It's a funny one this. The magic cast that makes PChar(nil) into a pointer to a null char is powerful. But the thing about casts is that they suppress errors. Onus is on you the coder and you no longer have compiler to check for you. Assigning char or string to a pchar variable is compiler error. Casting is right in one instance but not the other.

Answer (score 3):

In fact,

```
c:= PChar('*');
```

is compiled as

```
mov [c],$0000002a
```

as if it was written:

```
c:= PChar(ord('*'));
```

Since `ord('*')=$2a`, it appears that the `'*'` character is type-cast to an integer (`NativeInt`), then this integer is converted to a pointer. So when you try to access the `c` content, you access the memory address `$0000002a`, which is invalid, and triggers an access violation.

When you compile:

```
c:= PChar('**');
```

It is generated as

```
   mov eax,$00548984
   mov [c],eax
```

In this case, a constant #0-ended text buffer (and not a Delphi `string`) is generated by the compiler within the executable, and `c` is set to its address.

The fact that `PChar('*')` does not behave the same is one "optimization" of the `char` type, which can be typecasted to an integer.
But I understand it may be confusing.

If you want just a pointer to a single '*', you can write either:

```
c:=PChar('*'#0);
c:=PChar(string('*'));
```

Which will work as expected, since both will by-pass the cast to the character ordinal value.

Comment: `c := '*'` is what is needed in fact.